# Show that the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$ is a Euclidean ring.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, normed-spaces, integral-domain, euclidean-algorithm

Let $$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]=\{a+b\sqrt 2 \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Since the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ forms a ring, the subset $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$ also forms a ring if it is closed under addition and multiplication.

**Addition:**

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$  with $x=a+b\sqrt2, y=c+d\sqrt2$ where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then

$x+y=(a+b\sqrt2)+(c+d\sqrt2)$
$x+y=(a+c)+(b+d)\sqrt2$

Since $a, c \in \mathbb{Z} \implies a+c \in \mathbb{Z}$

and

Since $b, d \in \mathbb{Z} \implies b+d \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\implies x+y \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$

Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ is closed under addition.

**Multiplication:**
Let $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$  with $x=a+b\sqrt2, y=c+d\sqrt2$ where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then
$xy=(a+b\sqrt2)(c+d\sqrt2)$
$xy=(ac+2bd)+(ad+bc)\sqrt2$

Since $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z} \implies ac+2bd \in \mathbb{Z}$

and

Since $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z} \implies ad+bc \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\implies xy \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$

Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ is closed under multiplication.

It is also an integral domain since $\mathbb{R}$ as a field is an integral domain.

Alternatively:
A non-trivial solution of

$(x+y\sqrt2)(a+b\sqrt2)=0$ gives for

$xb+ya \neq 0$ the equation

$\sqrt2=-\frac{xa+2yb}{xb+ya}$, a contradiction to the irrationality of $\sqrt2$. If $xb+ya=0$ it follows that $xa+2yb=0$. Since the determinant of this linear system seen as an equation for x and y is $2b^{2}-a^{2}$, the only solution is $x=y=0$ if $2b^{2}-a^{2}\neq 0$. If $2b^{2}-a^{2}=0$, the irrationality of $\sqrt2 \implies a=b=0$. Thus either $x+y\sqrt2=0$ or $a+b\sqrt2=0$.

How to apply two axioms of  Euclidean algorithm on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$.

Thanks.

Comment: What are those 2 axioms? Anyway, prove that the norm: $N(a+b\sqrt 2):=|a^2-2b^2|$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Multiplicativity is easy: If you let this ring act on itself by multiplication and take matrices with resect to the basis $1,\sqrt{2}$ you find that the norm is just the determinant.